# Android screen rotation on VMWare

Tags: android, screen, vmware

Is there any way to rotate Android screen that is installed on VMWare?

These keys don't work on VMWare:

KEYPAD_7, Ctrl-F11

KEYPAD_9, Ctrl-F12

Answer (score 4):

I think i can

I installed an application on my JellyBean that is Android x86 4.2 which change the rotation of my screen and after even **reboot**, **reset** nothing reset and screen was still same

after many hour of searching i found nothing works
some suggestion

the <kbd>Num</kbd> off  <kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd> doesn't work

But finally i got the solution

press <kbd>**ctrl + F9**</kbd> multiple times for me it was **3**
and also the other three are the following

#### <kbd>**ctrl + F9**</kbd>  for 0 or 360 degree

#### <kbd>**ctrl + F10**</kbd>  for 90 degree

#### <kbd>**ctrl + F11**</kbd> for 180 degree

#### <kbd>**ctrl + F12**</kbd> for 270 degree

Comment: Thanks! Just to add to this on Mac's VMWare Fusion I forgot to hold down the fn key as well as ctrl